# Curl in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I want to use curl in my codeigniter application. But I am getting null array.

My code is like this:

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$url = "http://url/checkweb.php"; 
$post_data = array ( 
    "foo" => "bar", 
    "query" => "Nettuts", 
    "action" => "Submit" 
);
$output = $this->curl->simple_post($url, $post_data);
```

`checkweb.php`:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

now actually I want to pass current url and it will check that its in my private database and if it is there then its ok else it will redirect to google.com because my code can't be copied on other domain

Comment: `$this->load->library('curl')`? Is it a custom library? Because otherwise you don't need to do that, `curl_*` is a php extension

Comment: There's nothing native to codeigniter here. Follow the normal debugging steps for curl http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Yep, [it is](http://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl).

Comment: @Damien yeah it is custome library available on internet

Comment: It is, but he's obviously not using it correctly/at all.

Comment: @AmalMurali He didn't mentioned it, and besides he's loading a library and using a completely diffent code - one which makes the library useless

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the cURL library, you should have this at the bare minimum.

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$url = "http://url/checkweb.php"; 
$post_data = array ( 
    "foo" => "bar", 
    "query" => "Nettuts", 
    "action" => "Submit" 
);
$output = $this->curl->simple_post($url, $post_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

URL passed to `cURL` should be absolute-full-with-domain.

Instead of:

```
$url = "url/checkweb.php";
```

try:

```
$url = "http://yourdomain.com/url/checkweb.php";
```