# called controller page of shopping_admin into ecommerce codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have created one codeigniter application named as ecommerce. In this application i have created another codeigniter application called as `shopping_admin` into the application folder of ecommerce. so how can i called controller page of `shopping_admin`? how to configure `shopping_admin`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want?

Why you did not make single application and use the ACL (user Access Control List) between admin and user.

But if you still insist make 2 application on one directory, maybe you can use CURL.
Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954514/curl-in-codeigniter)

sory for my bad english

Comment: i want to create two application in one codeigniter folder.