# Using Curl in codeigniter like this

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, curl

How to use cURL in codeigniter? I have API access like this, and i want use in codeigniter.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://portalpulsa.com/api/connect/';

$header = array(
    'portal-userid: userid',
    'portal-key: key',
    'portal-secret: secretkey',
);

$data = array(
    'inquiry' => 'S', // konstan
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curl in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954514/curl-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I don't know what the $result is (e.g. html, json, whatev) but there's no official maintained CI curl library, so I would just take the working code you have and put it in a controller. I suppose you could move the userId, etc to a config file if you wanted.

Comment: You forgot to close cURL connection after getting `$result` and also use `var_dump($result)`, not an `echo` for better debug.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CURL in codeigniter as you use it in core PHP. There is no official CURL library/stranded for codeigniter.

If you have requirement to use CURL multiple times in your project, You can write it as a **function in helper** class.